# create a trigger which will copy few data from other table after getting filtered from condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 5 tables. they are ---

```
create table customer
(
cust_name varchar2(20),
cust_id number(5),
date_of_birth date
)

insert into customer values('Mark',1,'10-JAN-1984');
insert into customer values('Sam',2,'22-FEB-1990');

create table bank
(
bank_name varchar2(20),
bank_id number(5)
)

insert into bank values(20,'HDFC');
insert into bank values(42,'ICICI');

create table location
(
bank_id  number(5),
loc_name  varchar2(20)
)
insert into location values(30,'Delhi');
insert into location values(30,'USA');

create table loan
(
cust_id number(5),
bank_id number(5),
st_date date
intrest number(5)
)



create table audit
(
cust_id number(5),
cust_name varchar2(20),
date_of_birth date,
bank_name varchar2(20),
st_date date,
loc_name  varchar2(20),
interest number(5)
)
```

I want to create a trigger on loan table, if any customer gets 0 interest, then details of that customer and his bank must be stored in audit table.

so if execute this code--

```
insert into loan values(1,20,'20-DEC-2011',0);
```

That means this customer is getting 0 interest, so his records and his bank records must be stored in audit table.

My trigger code is --

```
create  or replace  trigger trg_loan
after insert or update
on loan
for each row
declare
var_loc varchar2(50); 
var_name varchar2(50);
var_bankname varchar2(50);

begin

select cust_name into var_name from customer where cust_id = :new.cust_id;
select bank_name into var_bankname from bank where bank_id = :new.bank_id;
select loc_name into var_loc from location where loc_id = :new.loc_id;

    IF (:new.interest = 0) THEN
insert into audit
values(:new.cust_id,var_name,:new.date_of_birth,var_bankname,:new.st_date,var_loc,:new.interest);

    END IF; 
end;
```

so this trigger is created  with compilation error.and it also does not  serve my interest.

Comment: Without a posted error and a question mark it's difficult to see what your problem is. However, at first glance `:new.date_of_birth` is incorrect as `date_of_birth` doesn't exist in the `loan` table. You also seem to be inserting a lot of strings into `date` data-types.

Comment: Is my code right if we exclude date_of_birth. I want insert data in audit table if a customer gets 0 interest in loan  table. The trigger which I created doesn't do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Firstly understand this logic that ,if you are refering `:new.[variable_name]` inside the trigger then it should always be referred for those column of the table on which trigger is been applied.
  For Eg : In you case  trigger is applied on `loan` table ,so only `cust_id number(5),
  bank_id number(5),
  st_date date
  intrest number(5)` is been used with `:new` keyword.
- Secondly following errors are found when creating trigger.

  **Compilation errors for TRIGGER SCOTT.TRG_LOAN**

  **Error: PLS-00049**: bad bind variable 'NEW.INTEREST'
  Line: 12
  Text: IF (:new.interest = 0) THEN

  **Reason**:you have used the script for creating  the table with column name `intrest not interest` ,please alter the table name to interest .

  **Error: PLS-00049**: bad bind variable 'NEW.LOC_ID'
  Line: 15
  Text: select loc_name into var_loc from location where loc_id = :new.loc_id;

  **Reason**:you cannot refer `:new.loc_id` in this trigger as this is not the part of `loc` table column.

  **Error**: PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.DATE_OF_BIRTH'
  Line: 17
  Text:  values(:new.cust_id,var_name,:new.date_of_birth,var_bankname,:new.st_date,var_loc,:new.interest);

  **Reason**:Again date_of_birth is not a column of loc table ,in your case fetch the data from customer table like

  `select cust_name,date_of_birth into var_name,var_dob from customer where cust_id = :new.cust_id;` and then use this `var_dob` variable when inserting into `audit` table

  Error: PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.INTEREST'
  Line: 17
  Text: values(:new.cust_id,var_name,:new.date_of_birth,var_bankname,:new.st_date,var_loc,:new.interest);

  **Reason**:Same as above.

**Suggestion** : If you only want to insert data into audit table in case of `0` interest value ,then put all the select statement inside the if clause because there is no need to fetch these value if the interest value is not zero .

creating trigger [trigger oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm#BABCIBBJ)